# How to make an OUTER JOIN return ZERO instead of NULL

Tags: sql-server, join

I am trying to accomplish this on SQL Server. The simplest table structure with data is shown below.

```
Table: Blog

BlogID | Title
-------+--------
  1    | FirstBlog
 23    | Pizza

Table: User

UserID | Name
-------+-----------
123    | james
444    | John

Table: UserBlogMapping

UserBlogMappingID | BlogID | UserID
------------------+--------+------
1                 |    1   |  123
```

I want to get `FormID` and `UserBlogMappingID` in one SQL query. If provided `UserID` is not in the mapping table, return ZERO otherwise return the valid `userBlogMappingID`. I am trying to run the below query but its not correct.

```
SELECT 
    B.BlogID, 
    BUM.BlogUserMappingID 
FROM 
    Blog AS B
        LEFT JOIN BlogUserMapping AS BUM ON B.BlogID = BUM.BlogID
WHERE 
    (B.BlogID = 23)  -- it exists in the table
    AND BUM.userID = 444 -- it is NOT in the mmaping table but I want a ZERO return in such case
```

**Assumption:**
We can assume that the `UserID` provided in the WHERE clause is always a valid `UserID` and is present in the `User` table.

Comment: Why do you need  UserBlogMappingID

Comment: @Paparazzi i need to use it in subsequent business logic.

Answer (score 7):

You can use either `ISNULL()` or `COALESCE()` function:

```
SELECT 
    BlogID = B.BlogID, 
    BlogUserMappingID = COALESCE(BUM.BlogUserMappingID, 0)
-- ...
```

or the more verbose `CASE` expression:

```
--  BlogUserMappingID = CASE WHEN BUM.BlogUserMappingID IS NULL 
--                          THEN 0 ELSE BUM.BlogUserMappingID 
--                      END
```

The second correction that the query needs is to move the condition - regarding the table on the right side of the `LEFT` join - from `WHERE` to `ON` (otherwise the left join becomes an inner join):

```
FROM 
    Blog AS B
        LEFT JOIN BlogUserMapping AS BUM ON  B.BlogID = BUM.BlogID
                                         AND BUM.userID = 444 
WHERE 
    B.BlogID = 23 ;
```

---

To avoid multiple rows with same `BlogID`, you could use an inline subquery with `TOP 1`, instead of the left join:

```
SELECT 
    BlogID = B.BlogID, 
    BlogUserMappingID = COALESCE(
        (SELECT TOP (1) BUM.BlogUserMappingID
         FROM BlogUserMapping AS BUM 
         WHERE B.BlogID = BUM.BlogID
           AND BUM.userID = 444
         ORDER BY BUM.BlogUserMappingID DESC
        ), 0)
FROM 
    Blog AS B
WHERE 
    B.BlogID = 23 ;
```

Comment: What does your last statement mean? Could you please clarify.

Comment: It means that if you keep the original FROM and WHERE, the row with `23, Pizza` will not appear in the results. I assume you want it to appear.

Comment: The query is returning more than one rows if there are more than one records in the 'BlogUserMapping' table against a certain 'BlogID' (not just the one with matching 'BUM.UserID'). For NO matching 'BUM.UserID', it works fine.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

```
ISNULL(count(*), 0)
```